# Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I don't understand why I'm getting this error when trying to populate this table. There is nothing in the table at the moment so I don't understand why there would be a duplicate...

This is the code I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO Suppliers
(supp_id,company_name,town,phone)
Values
("ADT217","AdTec","Birmingham","0121-368-1597"),
("CPS533","CPS","Maidenhead","01382-893715"),
("FCL162","ForComp Ltd","Nottingham","01489-133722"),
("KBC355","KBC Computers","Glasgow","0141-321-1497");
```

**suppliers table...**

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers(
    supp_id int NOT NULL,
    company_name character(15) NOT NULL,
    town character(15)
    phone character(15)
primary key(supp_id)
);
```

Comment: Which column is your primary key?

Comment: Please edit your question with the definition of the table.

Comment: supp_id is probably an integer type instead of a char/varchar.

Comment: the  supp_id is the primary key on the suppliers table

Comment: Perhaps there's an id column that's not set to auto-increment. Really, without the table definition this is just idle speculation.

Comment: Is this the *real* output of `Show create Table`? There are 2 `,` missing for a valid create statement... Be aware, mysql is case sensitive (for table names) on unix systems by default. `Suppliers != suppliers`. Maybe you are running your statements on a "wrong" table?

Answer (score 4):

This occurs when you have a primary key but do not give it an initialization value.  The insert itself is causing the duplication.

In your case, two possibilities come to mind:

1. `supp_id` is the primary key and declared as a number.  In older versions of MySQL, I think the string values get silently converted to numbers.  Because the leading characters are letters, the value is 0.
2. You have another `id` field that is the primary key, but given no value and not declared `auto_increment`.

EDIT:

I suspect you want the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    supplierId int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
    supp_name varchar(255) unique,
    company_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    town varchar(15),
    phone varchar(15)
);

INSERT INTO Suppliers(supp_name, company_name, town, phone)
    Values ('ADT217', 'AdTec', 'Birmingham', '0121-368-1597'),
           ('CPS533', 'CPS', 'Maidenhead', '01382-893715'),
           ('FCL162', 'ForComp Ltd', 'Nottingham', '01489-133722'),
           ('KBC355', 'KBC Computers', 'Glasgow', '0141-321-1497');
```

Some notes:

- Usually you want `varchar()` rather than `char()`, unless you really like lots of spaces at the end of strings.
- I added a unique supplier name to the table and declared the id to be a `auto_increment`.
- Single quotes are ANSI standard for string constants.  MySQL (and some other databases) allow double quotes, but there is no reason to not use the standard.

Comment: 1.) Shouldn't this lead to errors for the insert? (Incorrect Integer Value)?

Comment: could it be  that the supp_id is a  int not a char or varchar?

Comment: ive tried changing it to a varchar but is not working :(

Comment: @jmc1690 Please post your table definition (`SHOW CREATE TABLE Suppliers`)

Comment: @dognose . . . Interesting.  It definitely generates an error in more recent versions.  I wonder if earlier versions did silent conversion, because the OP is definitely indicating that that is not the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's why I was "asking" - but unless we know the exact version, it might be hard to find the causing issue. Also I have no clue, why the statement generated by `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would be malformated...

Comment: All MySQL Server versions try to coerce strings to numbers like this, but the default value for `SQL_MODE` in 5.6 causes the error to be thrown instead.  (Same for malformed timestamps/datetimes, btw).

Answer (score 1):

With your table you can get the error like "Incorrect Integer Value", but depending on MySQL server configuration it can do conversion(string->int) automatically for your query string must become "0" as result of this it makes 2 rows with 0 as supp_id and get error **Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'**. I guess you are using *InnoDB* as table type, in this case query will run as transaction and it will rollback after first error(for this example it will be second row).

```
DROP TABLE suppliers; -- Will drop your old table
CREATE TABLE suppliers(
supp_id varchar(30) NULL, -- You can set length as you wish
company_name character(15) NOT NULL,
town character(15),
phone character(15),
primary key(supp_id)
);

INSERT INTO Suppliers
(supp_id,company_name,town,phone)
Values
("ADT217","AdTec","Birmingham","0121-368-1597"),
("CPS533","CPS","Maidenhead","01382-893715"),
("FCL162","ForComp Ltd","Nottingham","01489-133722"),
("KBC355","KBC Computers","Glasgow","0141-321-1497");
```

After changing type insert will work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress, when we clone the website, the media and user roles are not working. The error is as below:

> WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO `wp_334_actionscheduler_logs` 
>        (`action_id`, `message`, `log_date_gmt`, `log_date_local`) 
> VALUES (0, 'action complete via WP Cron', '2021-02-17 05:29:40', 
>         '2021-02-17 05:29:40')
> ```
>
> made by
>
> ```
> do_action_ref_array('action_scheduler_run_queue'), 
> WP_Hook->do_action, 
> WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
> ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->run, 
> ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->do_batch, 
> ActionScheduler_Abstract_QueueRunner->process_action, 
> do_action('action_scheduler_after_execute'), 
> WP_Hook->do_action,
> WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
> ActionScheduler_Logger->log_completed_action, 
> ActionScheduler_DBLogger->log
> ```